# Why the img tag expand beyond its width?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple page: two **centered** thumbnails images. Each one links to its original image. Here is the code (I've removed some part for clarity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .column1, .column2 {
      width:50%;
      float:left;
      }

      div img {
      display:block;
      margin:20px auto;
      width:300px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="column1">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="maelstrom_mini.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="maelstrom_mini.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The issue is that very subtle: Each image is only 300px wide, but the anchor boxes are wider that the image it is supposed to contain. It makes the image "clickable" above its surface. I can't figure out how to tell the anchor not to spread to all its column.

When I remove the `display:block` attribute in the style sheet, then it solves that issue, but my pictures are no longer centered in regards to the containing column.

What's the correct solution to have both correct presentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed your problem,

I've added a wrapping div around the a and img tag setting that width to 300px, then setting the images width to 100% like so,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .column1, .column2 {
      width:49%;
      float:left;
      border: 1px solid red;
      }

      div img {
      width:100%;
      }

      #img-wrap{

      width:300px;
       margin:20px auto;
      display: block;
      }


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="column1">
      <div id="img-wrap">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="" />
      </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <div id="img-wrap">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="" />
      </a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

which can be found to work here > http://jsfiddle.net/3se2V/3/

Comment: You should change `img-wrap` to a class, since ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: All right @rusty009 your solution solved my issue. As suggested by Tom I used a class instead of an id. But then, I am confused: why does introducing a `div` layer fix the whole thing? I anyone has a good resource on that topic, I am highly interested in it. The more I am diving in CSS, the more I find it error-prone. Like dealing with a complex software configuration file, with no manuals, and unexpected behavior all the time! :-/ Anyway thanks to everyone involved in the resolution :-)

Comment: I'm no CSS expert, however, what I think is happening is that the 'auto' margin in your img tag is being centered in the middle of the <div> AND your <a> tag, so <a> is stretching the breadth of your column classes and is not being wrapped around your image. By adding an extra div to wrap around your image, only that is being centered with respect to your column classes and so everything inside it is scaling to the size of the wrapped div.

Comment: ok I guess I see the point. The extra `div.img-wrap`, taking the `margin:10px auto`, is stretched. Its content does not since I removed the `margin:10px auto` from the `img`. Ok I guess I get it. (I really need to train my **CSS muscle**, and read advanced CSS books ;-) ) .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the `margin:20px auto;` on the img:

Change this:

```
div img {
    display:block;
    margin:20px auto;
    width:300px;
}
```

to this:

```
div { margin: 20px 0; }

div img {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px;
}
```

Comment: Nope sorry. Just tried it does not seem to solve my issue. What was your idea begin removing the vertical margin please and moved it into the `div`?

Answer (score 0):

The only time that I can replicate the issue is if I add `display:block` to all `a` elements. So, I suggest adding this to your css:

```
div a {
  display:inline;
}
```

That might resolve your issue.

Comment: Sorry @SeasonEnds it didn't. I've just tried. Anyway, thank you for the help! :-)